# Could someone please help me with why is this happening? Python invalid syntax error

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
list1 = []
if x in range(100):
    for (x % 5) == 0:
        list1.append(x)
    return list1
```

I get an invalid syntax error for "=". I don't understand why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got your `if` and `for` mixed up, you need :

```
list1 = []
for x in range(100):
    if (x % 5) == 0:
        list1.append(x)
return list1
```

`for` is for iterating and `if` is for checking the conditions.

**P.S** - Since, I can't seem to be sure of the indentation, if the `return list1` is indented one step further, you would return from the first iteration of the for loop (hence returning either an empty list or a list with a single element), I fixed that since that is not what most programs are looking for.

Comment: oh uh, now i'm getting a return outside the function error T_T

Comment: Is your code in a function? If not, you don't need the `return` statement.

Comment: Then, you don't need the `return` statement, the `list1` gets built up and you can use it in your code without the `return`.

Answer (score 2):

pythonic version ;)

```
list1 = [x for x in range(100) if x % 5 == 0]
```